# Fonts render differently on Firefox for a particular webpage

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, google-fonts

I am developing a landing page for a website at:

https://emotional-wellbeing.com/

The page renders fine in Chrome, but in Firefox the Open Sans Condensed fonts do not show at all. I have tried several changes from this forum, but none have helped.

Google fonts include:

`<link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700|Open+Sans+Condensed:700" as="style"  onload="this.rel='stylesheet'"/>`

The page is Open Sans font, except for:

```
<div class="sectionmainheadline"><h1 style="font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif; font-weight:700; font-stretch: condensed;">"Discover How You Can <span style='color: #3a9921;'>Melt Away</span> Away Your Stress & <span style='color: #3a9921;'>Overcome </span>Your Anxiety,<br/><span class='underline'>In As Little As 5 Minutes From Now</span>"</h1></div>
```

I am using Bootstrap 4.

You can see how it looks on Chrome here:

[image: Chrome version]

But on Firefox the red circled area does not look Open Sans Italic, and the blue circled area is god knows what font!:

[image: Firefox version]

How can I get these circled areas looking like Chrome versions? I am out of ideas.

Comment: Looks like this `<link rel="preload" […] as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'"/>` does not work as intended in FF to begin with. As soon as I change the `rel` to `stylesheet` manually in inspector, the mentioned parts show up in the desired font fine.

Comment: Cheers - yes, that was the problem. Thanks for solving it :)

Comment: @Sylv99: when the system lets you, you may click on the tick icon adjacent to the answer below, to mark the question as solved. This is not mandatory here, but it is encouraged.

Comment: Note: all of your links are broken at the bottom of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this

```
 <link rel="preload" […] as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'"/>
```

does not work as intended in FF to begin with. As soon as I change the `rel` to `stylesheet` manually in inspector, the mentioned parts show up in the desired font fine.

Since I am not even seeing a request for the stylesheet URL before that, I would assume that it is not the `onload` part that is going wrong here, but that FF does not want to preload stylesheets this way in general yet(?).